# How does "alignParentBottom" work on phones with a control bottom bar?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Image to the Question
[image]

When I set

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

the text moves to the very bottom on the screen (Just see the blue rectangle on the android screen in the Image where we tap to control the mobile).

However it works correctly on my Samsung device but I don't have any idea of how it will look in Nexus or other phones which have control buttons on screen as such the one in the `AndroidStudio`.

Comment: and it will work correctly with other phones. it's only a rendering problem in your case

Comment: I think it's a good idea to have the xml as part of the picture but please post it as part of this question as well.

Comment: please paste your xml code i have understood your problem.

Comment: Post your xml code in above question please.

Comment: Try with static height and widh of imageview.

Answer (score -1):

use to linear layout inside of relative layout and give it match_parent both height and width.

like as below:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        //write your contents here which you give in relative layout

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. As I cannot overlap text on image with miner layout. Any other possible solution?

Comment: for small screen size users you have to use scroll view if you don't want to overlap to text on image.